# how to create subsets of variables in SAS using a criteria

Tags: sas

I am trying to run a regression with two independent variables automatically selected (meeting a certain criterion) from a variable list. For example, my variable list is:

```
Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4 Var5
```

I am trying to run 10 regressions using the pattern:

```
outcomeVar = var1 var2
OutcomeVar = var1 var3
.
.
.
OutcomeVar = var2 var3
.
.
.
OutcomeVar = var4 Var5
```

I am trying to generate a macro that will contain a loop that will automatically build these regressions. I am trying to use the `%scan` function to generate this loop but cannot formulate a criteron for variable selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested loop is one option :

```
%MACRO COMBI ;
  %LET NVAR = 5 ;
  %DO X = 1 %TO %EVAL(&NVAR - 1) ;
    %DO Y = %EVAL(&X + 1) %TO &NVAR ;
      %LET OUTCOMEVAR = VAR&X VAR&Y ;
      %PUT &OUTCOMEVAR ;
      /* do something else with outcomevar */      
    %END ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;
%COMBI ;
```

If your variables aren't actually numbered and sequential, you'd need to adopt a slightly different approach :

```
%MACRO COMBI ;
  %LET VARLIST = somevar thisvar thatvar varx vary ;
  %LET NVAR = %SYSFUNC(countw(&VARLIST)) ;
  %DO X = 1 %TO %EVAL(&NVAR - 1) ;
    %DO Y = %EVAL(&X + 1) %TO &NVAR ;      
      %LET OUTCOMEVAR = %SYSFUNC(scan(&VARLIST,&X)) %SYSFUNC(scan(&VARLIST,&Y)) ;
      %PUT &OUTCOMEVAR ;
      /* do something else with outcomevar */      
    %END ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;
%COMBI ;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering my question. Let me try this.

Comment: I modified the */do something else with outcomevar*/ section and generated the following code. I am a new user of this site and hence couldn't format the comment below in the correct way. But if you copy and paste it in SAS, I am sure it will show up in a neat manner.

Comment: %MACRO Reg;
  %LET VARLIST = AgeAtStart Height Weight Diastolic Systolic;
  %LET NVAR = %SYSFUNC(countw(&VARLIST)) ;
  %DO X = 1 %TO %EVAL(&NVAR - 1) ;
    %DO Y = %EVAL(&X + 1) %TO &NVAR ;      
      %LET status_c = %SYSFUNC(scan(&VARLIST,&X)) %SYSFUNC(scan(&VARLIST,&Y)) ;
      %PUT &status_c ;
        proc logistic data = heart desc;
        model &status_c 
  ods output ParameterEstimates = est&X&Y; 
  ods output FitStatistics = fit&X&Y;
    run;
      
    %END ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;
%Reg ;

Comment: The macro is running fine. However, if I call the macro reg by running "%Reg;", I am getting the error message "ERROR: Macro keyword LET appears as text.".

Comment: %MACRO Reg;
  %LET VARLIST = AgeAtStart Height Weight Diastolic Systolic;
  %LET NVAR = %SYSFUNC(countw(&VARLIST)) ;

  
  %DO X = 1 %TO %EVAL(&NVAR - 1) ;
    %DO Y = %EVAL(&X + 1) %TO &NVAR ;      
      %LET IndepVar = %SYSFUNC(scan(&VARLIST,&X)) %SYSFUNC(scan(&VARLIST,&Y)) ;
       
      %PUT IndepVar ;
        proc logistic data = heart desc;
        model status_c = &IndepVar;
  ods output ParameterEstimates = est&X&Y; 
  ods output FitStatistics = fit&X&Y;
    run;
      
    %END ;
  %END ;
%MEND ;


%Reg ;

Comment: I really appreciate all your help.